# filtering json fileds without conditions using wso2 esb

Tags: json, wso2-esb

In **WSO2 ESB**,how to pass certain **json** fields as request?
And adding the remaining json fields with the response?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use API's if you want to pass json as the request, you can frame json request and test via SOAP UI by selecting the media type as `application/json`.
ESB will accept this request and then by default converts it into an XML format, you can use xpath to perform different instructions and then if you want json as the output of your API you need to use the below syntax before exiting your API.`<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json; charset=utf-8"/>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json; charset=utf-8"/>`

Comment: That's okay. But what my question is , For example, from API am getting fields like {"full_name:"","ph":"","id":""}. I need to pass through ESB only the field "full_name" as request and again after hitting the API, "ph" and "id" needs to be added with the response.

Comment: That's pretty simple, first store the input request in a property mediator, then call the endpoint, once you get response from the endpoint you can use xquery mediator to combine the request and response.